# How to draw a networkx MultiGraph for nested data that has nested nodes with sizes as values in the dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I am trying to show 2 graphs that are not connected which represent the data as follows -

```json
demo_data = {"TOPIC1": {"SIZE": 50, 
                        "WORDS": {"cat": 20, "dog": 30}}, 
             "TOPIC2": {"SIZE": 25, 
                        "WORDS": {"bat": 4, "rat": 9}}}
```

The data is flexible in the sense that I control how it is nested/looks. The main idea is to be able to show a graph like following -

*There are 2 main nodes - `Topic1` and `Topic2` with their sizes as 50 and 25 respectively.
Topic1 is connected/surrounded by `Cat` node with size 20 and `Dog` node with size 30.
Similarly for `Topic2`. `Topic1` and `Topic2` are not connected - but this is flexible.*
[image]
If a different representation of the data is more suited for that, then that works too.

How do I go about making that graph from the given data?
What I have tried so far is this -

```py
import networkx as nx

demo_data = {"TOPIC1": {"SIZE": 500, "WORDS": {"cat": 1, "dog": 300}}, "TOPIC2": {"SIZE": 25, "WORDS": {"bat": 50, "rat": 90}}}

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(demo_data.keys())
G.add_nodes_from(demo_data['TOPIC1']['WORDS'], node_size=demo_data['TOPIC1']['WORDS'].values())
G.add_nodes_from(demo_data['TOPIC2']['WORDS'], node_size=demo_data['TOPIC2']['WORDS'].values())
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
```

But the node sizes are not working, neither are the positions as I want them to be. It was also difficult to figure out how to add edges between existing nodes programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `node_size` you are providing is an attribute of the node itself. It does not impact how it is drawn.

The size of the node that is drawn needs to be passed in the `nx.draw` function as a `list`. The default node size is `300`.

One way of doing this would be like this:

```
demo_data = {"TOPIC1": {"SIZE": 50, 
                        "WORDS": {"cat": 20, "dog": 30}}, 
             "TOPIC2": {"SIZE": 25, 
                        "WORDS": {"bat": 4, "rat": 9}}}

for key in demo_data.keys():
  G.add_node(key, size=demo_data[key]["SIZE"] * 10)
  for animal, size in demo_data[key]["WORDS"].items():
    G.add_node(animal, size=size*10)
    G.add_edge(animal, key)
```

[image]

Comment: @jar I have edited the answer. The concept remains the same. Add your `node_size` in the draw function for the size to change. Kindly accept if it helps you